# Sinatra filename into params

Tags: regex, sinatra

I'm looking for some help defining a route in Sinatra which matches a filename with some optional params.

```
/:name-:size?-:colour?.format

i.e. /robert-50-red.png
```

However I want both size and colour to be optional parameters. So all the following paths would be supported.

```
/robert.png
/robert-50.png
/robert-50-red.png
```

Updated

Also needs to cover names formed from multiple words.

```
/Mr Robert Rawlins-50.png
```

I've played with the traditional routing syntax however not had much joy due to the hyphens.

In an ideal world these params would be named parameters in the collection i.e. params[:name] rather than just being listed in the params[:captures] collection.

Answer (score 1):

This route should work:

```
/:name-?:size?-?:colour?.:format
```

Your first example was almost right, but you need to add `?` after the hyphens as well to make them optional.

You had also presumably forgotten a colon in front of `format`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works nicely. One caveat however which I forgot to mention in my initial scope is that :name is not always one word.

It may sometimes be something such as "Mr Robert Rawlins-50.png" or something to that effect.

My mistake for not including that initial, sorry.

Comment: Actually, that said even when using single words the option above doesn't seem to play nice. It's something about those hyphens, if modify your suggest to use / instead of - it works like a charm, but with the hyphen it fails to detect size and thinks it's part of the name param.

Comment: @SirRawlins You probably need to use a Regexp as the URL parameter in that case. Sinatra is fine with that.

Comment: @SirRawlins Hm. Surprising (and undocumented) that Sinatra would be greedy when matching hyphens but not slashes. But yeah, it sounds like you want regex anyway.